Remote Desktop Disconnects Randomly on One Machine—Any Ideas?
I'm facing an issue with Remote Desktop on my local home network. I have two Windows computers, both directly wired to the gateway. While I can initiate a Remote Desktop session to both machines, one of them keeps disconnecting randomly.
Interestingly, I've tested AnyDesk on the problematic machine, and it works perfectly without any disconnections. The other machine on my network is working fine with Remote Desktop.
There are no firewalls or VPNs in use on either machine, so I'm trying to figure out what could be causing the issue on this specific machine. Has anyone else encountered this problem or have any ideas on what might be wrong?
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Good diagnosis using AnyDesk. That means you a fallback, if the MS app is problematic.
